# React Native fetch() not outputting body in console log

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using fetch() to get some data from an API. When testing in Postman the data is returned successfully as JSON. However, when testing from react native app on android I get a text/html response, not sure why. How can I view the body of the response from the text in console.log() to debug? When I do console.log(resp) I can not see the body.

```
       const response = await fetch('https://web.com/api/usersignup', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }, 
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
        .then(resp => {
            this.setState({spinner: false});
            console.log(resp);// output in console is pasted under this code
             return resp.text();

            //return resp.json();
        })
        .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log(responseJson);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({spinner: false});
            Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
            throw error;
        });
```

**Output I get in Metro Builder when using console.log(). Does not include body.**

```
Response {
  "_bodyBlob": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "63acc7d8-bd8a-4dd7-b33b-f0e4f202f97e",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
    },
  },
  "_bodyInit": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "63acc7d8-bd8a-4dd7-b33b-f0e4f202f97e",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
    },
  },
  "headers": Headers {
    "map": Object {
      "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "0",
      "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
      "date": "Sat, 09 Nov 2019 21:06:05 GMT",
      "server": "Apache",
      "x-ratelimit-limit": "60",
      "x-ratelimit-remaining": "59",
    },
  },
  "ok": true,
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": undefined,
  "type": "default",
  "url": "https://web.com/api/usersignup",
}
```

Comment: Have you tried axios? It's very helpful for http requests and provides a better response object.

Comment: Same issue, how can I actually output the body in console? There is some issue with the data being sent using POST to the server, and I need to get the full debug response from the API/server, how do I do that?

Comment: For axios this is the response schema: {
  data: {},
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {},
  config: {},
  request: {}
}

Comment: If you are not getting a data key, this is caused by your api, maybe you should debug this with an API testing tool like Postman.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print the body until the promise of first then is finished.

I made an example with your code: https://snack.expo.io/@egizas/fetch-print-body

```
const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, 
    //body: JSON.stringify(formData)
})
.then(resp => {
    console.log('Printing out not json');
    console.log(resp);
    return resp.json();
})
.then((responseJson) => {
 console.log('Printing out json'); 
 console.log(responseJson);
})
.catch(error => {
    this.setState({spinner: false});
    Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
    throw error;
});
```

Just replace the endpoint and provide correct header.